# Java - Merge Two Arrays without Duplicates (No libraries allowed)

Tags: java, arrays

Need assistance with programming issue.

Must be in Java. Cannot use any libraries (Arraylist, etc.).

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0}
int[] b = {0, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 8}
```

Have to create an object referencing these two arrays in a method that merges them together, removes duplicates, and sorts them.

Here's my sort so far. Having difficulty combining two arrays and removing duplicates though.

```
int lastPos;
int index;
int temp;

for(lastPos = a.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {
    for(index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++) {
        if(a[index] > a[index+1]) {
            temp = a[index];
            a[index] = a[index+1];
            a[index+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are duplicates, which one do you want to remove.  Also, why no `ArrayList`?  It's in the standard Java SE, so there's never going to be a situation in which you won't have access to it.

Comment: You can add the arrays together, sort them and remove any consecutive numbers which are the same.

Comment: @ostrichofevil except for homework... ;)

Comment: Aaah, good point.  Okay, I'll think this through.

Comment: If I were doing this, I would probably sort the arrays individually - with a bubble sort, which is easy to write and can modify an array in-place (and looks suspiciously close to the shown code) - and then merge-walk the result, which is also guaranteed to be sorted; this is a variation of the approach previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge Two Arrays without Duplicates and Sort it (No libraries used).
Using an object.

```
public class MergeRemoveDupSort {    

public int[] mergeRemoveDupSortIt(int[] a, int[] b) {   
    int [] c = mergeIt(a,b);
    int [] d = removeIt(c);
    int [] e = sortIt(d);
    return e;
}

private int[] mergeIt(int[] a, int[] b) {   
    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];        
    int k=0;
    for (int n : a) c[k++]=n;        
    for (int n : b) c[k++]=n;   
    return c;
}

private int[] removeIt(int[] c) {  
    int len=c.length;
    for (int i=0;i<len-1;i++) 
        for (int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
            if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                for (int k=j;k<len-1;k++)
                    c[k]=c[k+1];
                --len;
            } 
    int [] r = new int[len];
    for (int i=0;i<r.length;i++)
        r[i]=c[i];
    return r;
}

private int[] sortIt(int[] a) {   
    for(int index=0; index<a.length-1; index++)
       for(int i=index+1; i<a.length; i++)
           if(a[index] > a[i]){
               int temp = a[index];
               a[index] = a[i];
               a[i] = temp;
           }
     return a;
}    

public void printIt(int[] a) {   
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        if (i!=a.length-1) System.out.print(",");
        else System.out.print("]");            
    }        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0};
    int[] b = {0, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 8};

    MergeRemoveDupSort array = new MergeRemoveDupSort();
    int [] r = array.mergeRemoveDupSortIt(a, b);
    array.printIt(r);        
}        
}
```

Comment: ^^THIS! Thanks for the assistance! I actually wedged them all into one method, tweaked a few things, but your assistance was awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Consider marking the answer as valid if this has helped you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> a method that merges them together, removes duplicates, and sorts them.

I suggest you break this down into helper methods (and *slightly* tweak the order of operations). Step 1, merge the two arrays. Something like,

```
static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        c[a.length + i] = b[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Step 2, sort the new array (your existing sort algorithm is fine). Like,

```
static void sortArray(int[] a) {
    for (int lastPos = a.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {
        for (int index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++) {
            if (a[index] > a[index + 1]) {
                int temp = a[index];
                a[index] = a[index + 1];
                a[index + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, remove duplicates. Step 3a, count `unique` values. Assume they're unique, and decrement by counting adjacent (and equal) values. Like,

```
static int countUniqueValues(int[] c) {
    int unique = c.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        while (i + 1 < c.length && c[i] == c[i + 1]) {
            i++;
            unique--;
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

Then step 3b, take the unique count and build your result with the previous methods. Like,

```
public static int[] mergeDedupSort(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = mergeArrays(a, b);
    sortArray(c);
    int unique = countUniqueValues(c);
    int[] d = new int[unique];
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        d[p++] = c[i];
        while (i + 1 < c.length && c[i] == c[i + 1]) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Then you can test it with your arrays like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0 };
    int[] b = { 0, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 8 };
    int[] c = mergeDedupSort(a, b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

And I get

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use IntStream like this.

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0};
    int[] b = {0, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 8};
    int[] merged = IntStream
        .concat(IntStream.of(a), IntStream.of(b))
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

Comment: I like this answer. Java 8 is so neat - brings over some of the things I like about C#.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that array **a** and array **b** are sorted, the following code will merge them into a third array **merged_array** without duplicates :

```
public static int[] get_merged_array(int[] a, int[] b, int a_size, int b_size)
{

  int[] merged_array = new int[a_size + b_size];


  int i = 0 , j = 0, x = -1;

  for(; i < a_size && j < b_size;)
  {
      if(a[i] <= b[j])
      {
          merged_array[++x] = a[i];

          ++i;
      }
      else          
      {
          if(merged_array[x] != b[j])
          {
              merged_array[++x] = b[j]; // avoid duplicates
          }

          ++j;
      }
  }

  --i; --j;

  while(++i < a_size)
  {
       merged_array[++x] = a[i];
  }

  while(++j < b_size)
  {
      merged_array[++x] = b[j];
  }

  return merged_array;
}
```

Hope this may help, all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0};
    int[] b = {0, 2, 11, 12, 5, 6, 8};
    int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
    int[] final = new int[a.length+b.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(int j : final){
        final[i++] = -1;
    }
    i = 0;
    for(int j : a){
        c[i++] = j;
    }
    for(int j : b){
        c[i++] = j;
    }
    boolean check = false;
    for(int j = 0,k = 0; j < c.length; j++){
        for(int l : fin){
            if( l == c[j] )
                check = true;
        }
        if(!check){
            final[k++] = c[j];
        } else check = false;
    }

} catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I prefer you to use Hashset for this cause it never allow duplicates
and there is another method in java 8 for arraylist to remove duplicates 
after copying all elements to c follow this code

```
List<Integer> d = array.asList(c);
List<Integer> final = d.Stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
final.forEach(System.out::println());
```

This code is lot much better than previous one and you can again transform final to array like this

```
int array[] = new int[final.size()];              
    for(int j =0;j<final.size();j++){
      array[j] = final.get(j);
    }
```

Hope my work will be helpful .

Answer (score -1):

Let me restate your question.

You want a program that takes two arbitrary arrays, merges them removing any duplicates, and sorts the result.

First of all, if you have access to any data structure, there are **much** better ways of doing this. Ideally, you would use something like a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

However, assuming all you have access to is arrays, your options are much more limited. I'm going to go ahead and assume that each of the two arrays initially has no duplicates.

Let's assume the first array is of length m and the second array is of length n.

```
int[] array1; // length m
int[] array2; // length n
```

First, let's sort both arrays.

```
Arrays.sort(array1);
Arrays.sort(array2);
```

This assumes you have access to the `Arrays` class which is part of the standard Java Collections Framework. If not, any reasonable merge implementation (like [MergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)) will do the trick.

The sorts will take `O(n log n + m log m)` with most good sort implementations.

Next, let's merge the two sorted arrays. First, we need to allocate a new array big enough to hold all the elements.

```
int[] array3 = new int[size];
```

Now, we will need to insert the elements of `array1` and `array2` in order, taking care not to insert any duplicates.

```
int index=0, next=0, i=0, j=0;
int last = Integer.MAX_INT;
while(i < m || j < n) {
    if(i == m)
        next = array2[j++];
    else if(j == n)
        next = array1[i++];
    else if(array1[i] <= array2[j])
        next = array1[i++];
    else
        next = array2[j++];

    if(last == next)
        continue;

    array3[index++] = next;
}
```

Now, you have your array. Just one problem - it could have invalid elements at the end. One last copy should take care of it...

```
int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array3, index + 1);
```

The inserts and the final copy will take `O(n + m)`, so the overall efficiency of the algorithm should be `O(n log n + m log n)`.